# Does ''homology vanishes eventually'' imply ''homotopy vanishes eventually''?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homotopy-theory

Let $X$ be a connected CW complex.

Assume there is an integer $N\geq 0$ such that the singular homology $H_n(X)=0$ vanishes for all $n\geq N$.

> Is there an integer $M\geq 0$ such that $\pi_m(X)=0$ for all $m\geq M$?

Comment: The answer is no in general (see $S^n$, for example), but there are some partial results under certain conditions for rational homotopy groups $\pi_*(X) \otimes \mathbb{Q}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try $X=S^2$ (and look at the table on [this page](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_groups_of_spheres#Table))

Comment: Ah, of course. Sorry, this was a stupid question.

Comment: But do we know that they don't become $0$ eventually?